# How to assign dynamic value in the value field of ngb-progressbar in angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using `ngb-progressbar` in angular 6 as below:

```
<p>
    <ngb-progressbar
        type="info"
        [value]="{{percentageCompleted}}"
        [striped]="true"
        [animated]="true">

        <i>{{percentageCompleted}}</i>

    </ngb-progressbar>
</p>
```

The problem I am facing here is to assign dynamic values into `[value]`. The `{{percentageCompleted}}` inside `<i>` is printing value but not inside `[value]`.

In `component.ts` file:

```
public percentageCompleted: number;

constructor(){
    this.percentageCompleted = 20;
}
```

Can somebody suggest me how can I assign dynamic value to `[value]` field of `ngb-progressbar` in angular 6?

**UPDATE:**

```
<ngb-progressbar
    type="info"
    [value]="percentageCompleted"
    [striped]="true"
    [animated]="true">
```

Error:

> **Error:** ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value: undefined'. Current value: 'value: 4.75'.

Code from `constructor`

```
this.sharedMessage.shareMessage$.subscribe((data) => {
    this.message = data; 
    this.prevQuestionId = this.message[0]; 
    this.currentQuestionId = this.message[1]; 
    this.nextQuestionId = this.message[2]; 
    this.percentageCompleted = this.message[3]; 
    console.log("I am message from questionnaire home component>>>>>" + this.message);
})
```

Comment: try this `[value]="percentageCompleted"`

Comment: I got a new error as below:

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value: undefined'. Current value: 'value: 4.75'.

Can u suggest me, how can I solve this?

Comment: Where/When are you setting this value `4.75` to the `percentageCompleted` property?

Comment: The code inside constructor is as below:

this.sharedMessage.shareMessage$.subscribe((data) =>{
      this.message=data;
      this.prevQuestionId=this.message[0];
      this.currentQuestionId=this.message[1];
      this.nextQuestionId=this.message[2];
      this.percentageCompleted=this.message[3];
      console.log("I am message from questionnaire home component>>>>>"+this.message);
    })

I am setting values from another component.

Comment: Try moving that from `constructor` to the `ngAfterViewInit(){...}` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the brackets from `ngb-progressbar` value:

```
<ngb-progressbar
        type="info"
        [value]="percentageCompleted"
        [striped]="true"
        [animated]="true">
        <i>{{percentageCompleted}}</i>
</ngb-progressbar>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, after following your suggestion i got as error as below:
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value: undefined'. Current value: 'value: 4.75'.

Can you suggest me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. However, I solved my issue by assigning values inside ngOnIn(){} instead of inside constructor.

The answered that worked for me is as below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedMessage.shareMessage$.subscribe((data) =>{
  this.message=data;
  this.prevQuestionId=this.message[0];
  this.currentQuestionId=this.message[1];
  this.nextQuestionId=this.message[2];
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.percentageCompleted=this.message[3];
  },1000);
    })
  }
```